# Passing path to php returns undefined

Tags: javascript, php

i am trying to pass a path to a php script and the script is supposed to then return all image files in that path in a array but all i keep getting is undefined error, can someone help please.

```
function LoadGallery(dir_path) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "getimages.php",
    traditional: true,
    data:{ path : dir_path},
    type: "json",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data[0]);
    //    $("#image-container").val(data[0]);

    }
  });
}
```

PHP SCRIPT getimages:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['path'])){
    $dir = $_POST['path'];
    $img = array();

    if (is_dir($dir)) {
       if ($hnd = opendir($dir)) {
           while (false !== ($file = readdir($hnd))) {
               if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                    $img[] = $file;
                }
           }
           closedir($hnd);
        }
    }
    return $img;
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Could you add the actual error? We don't really know what's undefined.
if dir_path is undefined then the error might be before you even call `loadGallery`. Another thing, keep in mind that I could get a listing of all your files by passing a dir_path like ../, or ../../, or /home ... etc.

Comment: change **return $img;** --- to **echo json_encode($img);**

Comment: I agree a lot with the `json_encode()` usage already said by fellow commenters. But also, isn't it easier to use the `glob()` function to search for the images? It will return an array with all the paths to the pictures! Then you can `json_encode` them to get the result you need for JavaScript (or jQuery).

Comment: Not sure but it looks to me as if the data[0] array is undefined but this is what i am having problems with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your php code to return json with result.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['path'])){
    $dir = $_POST['path'];
    $img = array();

    if (is_dir($dir)) {
       if ($hnd = opendir($dir)) {
           while (false !== ($file = readdir($hnd))) {
               if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                    $img[] = $file;
                }
           }
           closedir($hnd);
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($img);
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: could you please console.log(data); and show me the result please ? with my code

Comment: @ Alaa M.jaddou I have it working but there is still a problem as i can't close the image preview popup.

Comment: could you be more clearly i miss understand what you say?

Comment: @ Alaa M.jaddou It is working now but when i click a thumb nail image i get a popup of a bigger image but then i can't close it

Comment: the popup not worked for me, and i get no result. :(